# How to properly display the object value to another separate page component after a button is clicked in React? (From object form to proper form)

Tags: reactjs, json, object, react-hooks, react-props

I have created a functionality for my "menu item buttons" to display their assigned data through an object format into a separate page component called "SidePage" (gained help also here in StackOverflow). What I am not sure is that if this functionality that I have created is a formal or effective one since I am planning to implement a backend functionality into my full main app. The functionality involves useState, onClick, and onSelected.

I used props to hold the resulting data after the "menu item button" is clicked.

(Chicken Button should be clicked first in order to display the menu item buttons)

[image: presentation]

SidePage source code:

```
import * as React from "react";
import { Typography } from "@mui/material";

export default function SidePage(props) {
  return (
    <div>
      <Typography sx={{ mt: 20 }}>Menu Item Details:</Typography>

      <div>{props.menuItemDetails}</div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

HomeOrderPage (main page) source code:

```
import * as React from "react";
import { useState } from "react";

import { Stack } from "@mui/material";
import ButtonCategoryStyle from "./ButtonCategoryStyle";

import ChickenButtons from "./categoryButtons/ChickenButtons";
import SidePage from "./SidePage";
const categories = ["Chicken"];

export default function HomeOrderPage() {
  const [myCategory, setMyCategory] = useState("");
  const [food, setFood] = useState(null);

  return (
    <div>
      <Stack spacing={0} direction="row">
        {categories.map((category) => (
          <ButtonCategoryStyle
            title={category.toLocaleUpperCase()}
            key={category}
            onClick={() => setMyCategory(category)}
          />
        ))}
      </Stack>

      <div>
        <p>
          {myCategory === "Chicken" && <ChickenButtons onSelected={setFood} />}
        </p>

  {/* ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------ */}
      </div>
      {/* Displays object after menu item is clicked and renders the side page to show the menu item details:: */}

      <div
        style={{
          backgroundColor: "blue"
        }}
      >
        <SidePage
          menuItemDetails={
            food && <pre sx={{ ml: 120 }}>{JSON.stringify(food, null, 2)}</pre>
          }
        />
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Full source code (CodeSandbox): https://codesandbox.io/s/nice-stack-question-page-component-data-transfer-ejebxz?file=/src/HomeOrderPage.jsx

What I also want is to store the property values of the object into variables (in order to display the details of the selected menu item button properly but I am not sure how to do this since I am baffled with using this.state or still using props for this.

Hoping for all of your response as this would help me a lot with my first big React project that I am working on. Thank you very much everyone!

Answer (score -1):

Since you already have props. Why copy it to state? Just keep single source of truth.